# Restoring vertical scroll in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, qtableview, qt4.8

I use C++, Qt 4.8.7, Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7.
My GUI application contains `QTableView`. I added slots, which handle `beginResetModel()` and `reset()` signals from my model. These slots are normally called, but the vertical scroll still scrolls always to the top of the whole list. How can I fix it? I need to restore current position. Note that during reset no row is deleted. So, the old rows content can be changed and/or new rows are added.

```
//before reset
current_top_row_number_ = table_view_->rowAt(0);

//after reset
table_view_->scrollTo(log_model_->index(current_top_row_number_, 0), QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try queuing the call to to `scrollTo`, e.g.

```
class MyWidget : public MyWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  int current_top_row_number_;
  QTableView table_view_;
  Q_SLOT void onResetModel() {
    table_view_->scrollTo(log_model_->index(current_top_row_number_, 0),
                          QAbstractItemView::PositionAtTop);
  }
  ...
public:
  MyWidget(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QWidget{parent} {     
    connect(table_view_, SIGNAL(modelReset()), SLOT(onResetModel(), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  }
};
```